# daemon threads in an app container

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, concurrency, xmpp

I read in [a post](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/message/189500) to the Smack forum recently that

> Starting daemon threads in a Java EE server is a big no no

Basically Smack's XMPPConnection starts one daemon thread to monitor incoming data
& another to send outgoing data from/to the jabber server respectively. Is it reasonable to use daemon threads to listen for write/reads in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, XMPPConnection creates two threads--one for listening/reading and one for writing.  But these only live as long as the XMPPConnection instance, which I assume is not forever.

> "Starting daemon threads in a Java EE server is a big no no"

Are you writing spec compliant EJB?  If so, then this applies.  The spec says don't do it.  EJB 2.1 specification:

> "The enterprise bean must not attempt
>   to manage threads. The enterprise bean
>   must not attempt to start, stop,
>   suspend, or resume a thread, or to
>   change a thread’s priority or name.
>   The enterprise bean must not attempt
>   to manage thread groups."

Or is it just a webapp that happens to be running in Tomcat?  If this is the case, then I do not see any fundamental problem.  Without the threads, your Smack client would be unable to communicate with the server.

Comment: It is the latter (webapp on Tomcat). Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Smack API for client connections only which are stand alone programs. First you should revisit the choice (or purpose) of Smack API inside a J2EE container.

Comment: I'm actually charged with maintaining an existing codebase which already uses Smack inside Tomcat. What are the reasons against using Smack in Tomcat (or a j2ee container) ?